# Symfony2 read route parameter

Tags: symfony, routes

This is my route

```
personeelslid_personeelslid_detail:
pattern: /personeelslid/detail/{personeelId}
defaults: 
    _controller: PersoneelPersoneelslidBundle:Personeelslid:detail
    _menu_icon: fa-user

locatiebeheer_kind_detail:
pattern: /locatiebeheer/kind/detail/{kindId}
defaults: { _controller: PersoneelLocatiemanagerBundle:KindDetail:detail }
```

In my menuBuilder I loop through all routes and fetch for example _menu_icon:

```
$routeObject = $this->_router->getRouteCollection()->get($route);               

$menu_icon = $routeObject->getDefault('_menu_icon');
```

How can I fetch the variable name personeelId, kindId, etc..
I need te keys so I can set the routeParameter attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom keys to `defaults` option if you want. Example:

```
personeelslid_personeelslid_detail:
path: /personeelslid/detail/{personeelId}
defaults: 
    _controller: PersoneelPersoneelslidBundle:Personeelslid:detail
    _menu_icon: fa-user
    my_custom_key: personeelId
```

and get it:

```
$myCustomKey = $routeObject->getDefault('my_custom_key');
```

IF you want to fetch the value of wildcard, you cant' do it like this way (by `getRouteCollection`), fetch it from Request object (e.g. `$request->attributes->all()`)..

Comment: Thanks, I knew this option. Was hoping for a more elegant way. I will do this way then.

Comment: @Bart I haven't seen better option yet, only this way or php's `explode` function and regex with `getRouteCollection` :)